# Repeat a sound/action every certain time

Tags: python, date, time, while-loop, repeat

I'm trying to write a Python program that reproduces a sound every certain hour, but it doesn't really work. When I test the code and the specified time comes, it will keep repeating the sound forever.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
currentHour = now.hour
currentMin = now.minute

#I also tested with if but it didn't work
while currentHour==15 and currentMin==33:
    os.system("aplay /home/pi/sound.wav") #Plays the sound thru aplay
```

Comment: What happens if your script crashes or the computer is restarted? You should use tools provided by your OS such as `cron` or Windows Task Scheduler  instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.

First of all, the `while` loop will most likely end in the first iteration and you want the program to continue till you tell it to.

In addition to that, you don't update the `now` variable inside the loop, which is basically a bad idea.

For example, this code will continue running and when it is `15:33`, a sound will be played only once.

```
myHour = 15
myMin = 33
is_played = False
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    currentHour = now.hour
    currentMin = now.minute
    if currentHour == myHour and currentMin == myMin and not is_played:
        is_played = True
        os.system("aplay /home/pi/sound.wav")
    if currentHour != myHour or currentMin != myMin:
        is_played = False
```

[Xiaotian Pei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700650/xiaotian-pei) suggested a great idea, to efficiently use your CPU resource, lets use the `Timer` module:

```
def to_play_sound(hour, min):
    now = datetime.now()
    currentHour = now.hour
    currentMin = now.minute
    if currentHour == hour and currentMin == min and not is_played:
        is_played = True
        os.system("aplay /home/pi/sound.wav")
    if currentHour != myHour or currentMin != myMin:
        is_played = False
while True:
    t = Timer(30.0, to_play_sound, [15, 33])
    t.start()
```

[J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279) has also suggested a great idea:

```
import datetime
import subprocess
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    # compute `deadline`
    while True:
        deadline = now.replace(hour=hour, minute=min)
        if deadline > now:
            break
        else:
            deadline += datetime.timedelta(1)
    sleep_until(deadline) # sleep
    subprocess.check_call(['aplay', '/home/pi/sound.wav']) # play the sound!
```

Read how `sleep_until` was implemented [here](https://gist.github.com/zed/7770492).

Comment: this will play the song a lot of times, between 15:33 and 15:34

Comment: @RodrigoLópez - that's right. It's not an issue in my opinion. However, to make it interesting, I have changed the code to answer this requirement. ;)

Comment: You misunderstood how `Timer()` works: `to_play_sound` function is called exactly once but you want it to be called perpetually. Try the code  [`sleep_until(deadline)`](https://gist.github.com/zed/7770492) in a loop instead, where `deadline` could be computed as `while True: deadline = now.replace(hour=hour, minute=min) if deadline > now: break else: deadline += timedelta(1)`

Comment: You might have noticed that the loop that computes `deadline` has no `sleep_until()` in it. You need another loop to call `sleep_until()` in it. The loop from my comment computes a new deadline that is all. `while True: (put deadline loop here) # use deadline *after* inner loop: sleep_until(deadline); play_sound()` end of outer loop.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, your review please ;)

Comment: almost there 1. use `now = datetime.now()` in the outer loop so that it could be able to work more than one day 2. you could use `subprocess.check_call(['aplay', '/home/pi/sound.wav'])` to raise an exception if the file can't be played (it also avoids running the shell unnecessarily).

Comment: 1. the import is incorrect, run the code before posting it or specify explicitly that you have not tested it. 2. Put "python scheduler" into your favorite search engine and read the source of various schedulers, to see many many other problems that should be handled 3. Remove all the custom code and use `cron`, Windows Task  Scheduler instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's a complement to @bshuster13 's answer.

What you need is actually a `timer`. Using a busy loop and detect if it's the right time to do something is not a good idea. Take a look at [`Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) in python. I think you will come up with a better solution.